# how to apply pattern matching on the file name using spark(scala)

Tags: scala, hadoop, pattern-matching, spark-streaming

I am monitoring a directory in `hdfs` and if a file is put into it i want to retrieve the name of the file entering the directory and apply pattern matching so as to sort them based on names so far i have been able to retrieve the file path.which gives me the file name but i don't know how to proceed further with pattern matching

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.{FileSplit, TextInputFormat}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.{NewHadoopRDD}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
object path {

def main(args: Array[String]) {

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple     Application").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val fc = classOf[TextInputFormat]
val kc = classOf[LongWritable]
val vc = classOf[Text]

val path :String = "/home/hduser/Desktop/foldername"
val text = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, fc ,kc, vc, sc.hadoopConfiguration)
println("++++++++++++++   "+text)
val linesWithFileNames = text.asInstanceOf[NewHadoopRDD[LongWritable, Text]].mapPartitionsWithInputSplit((inputSplit, iterator) => {
val file = inputSplit.asInstanceOf[FileSplit]


println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>   "+file.getPath)



iterator.map(tup => (file.getPath, tup._2))
}
)
linesWithFileNames.collect()
}
}
```

this gives me the path like 
**`/home/hduser/Desktop/folder_name/XYZ_123_pqr_abc_FILENAME`**

and i want to apply pattern matching based on the file name start....here it will based on **XYZ**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specific enough, i think. From context of your question i assume XYZ are digits and you intend to sort files by that numbers, if that's the case consider the following example:

```
val matchStart = """^(\d{3})""".r.unanchored
val number = file match {
  case matchStart(number, _*) => number.toInt
  case _ => ???//error handling, not necessarily unimplemented error
}
```

Now having extracted the number from the begining of the file name you can perform sorting etc.
**Edit**

Following information in comment answer would be similar:

```
val matchStart = """^([a-zA-Z1-9]{3})""".r.unanchored
val prefix = file match {
  case matchStart(a, _*) => a
  case _ => ???//error handling, not necessarily unimplemented error
}
```

Having the prefix extracted you can do anything you want with it.

Comment: sorry for not being specific,but here XYZ are alphabets .....its just a random combination of alphabets based on which the sorting has to be done......what i intend to do is to match the first three letters and then chose the schema file...based on the file name.....hence matching the file name is very imp here.....help will be appreciated